# PostgreSQL if query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

Is there a way to select records based using an if statement?

My table looks like this:

```
id | num | dis 
1  | 4   | 0.5234333
2  | 4   | 8.2234
3  | 8   | 2.3325
4  | 8   | 1.4553
5  | 4   | 3.43324
```

And I want to select the `num` and `dis` where `dis` is the lowest number...  So, a query that will produce the following results:

```
id | num | dis 
1  | 4   | 0.5234333
4  | 8   | 1.4553
```

Comment: If there are two row with the same num and dis, but different ids, which of these should be returned? Or do you want both? Or is that situation impossible?

Comment: Approximately how many rows will there be in your table? And how many groups? The size of the table is relevant for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the rows with the minimum value within the group:

```
SELECT id, num, dis
FROM table1 T1
WHERE dis = (SELECT MIN(dis) FROM table1 T2 WHERE T1.num = T2.num)
```

Or you could use a join to get the same result:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.num, T1.dis
FROM table1 T1
JOIN (
    SELECT num, MIN(dis) AS dis
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY num
) T2
ON T1.num = T2.num AND T1.dis = T2.dis
```

If you only want a single row from each group, even if there are ties then you can use this:

```
SELECT id, dis, num FROM (
    SELECT id, dis, num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY dis) rn
    FROM table1
) T1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Unfortunately this won't be very efficient. If you need something more efficient then please see [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi)'s page on [selecting rows with a groupwise maximum for PostgreSQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/26/postgresql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/). Here he suggests several ways to perform this query and explains the performance of each. The summary from the article is as follows:

> Unlike MySQL, PostgreSQL implements
>   several clean and documented ways to
>   select the records holding group-wise
>   maximums, including window functions
>   and DISTINCT ON.
>
> However to the lack of the loose index
>   scan support by the PostgreSQL’s
>   optimizer and the less efficient usage
>   of indexes in PostgreSQL, the queries
>   using these function take too long.
>
> To work around these problems and
>   improve the queries against the low
>   cardinality grouping conditions, a
>   certain solution described in the
>   article should be used.
>
> This solution uses recursive CTE’s to
>   emulate loose index scan and is very
>   efficient if the grouping columns have
>   low cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (num) id, num, dis
FROM tbl
ORDER BY num, dis
```

Or if you intend to use other RDBMS in future, use this:

```
select * from tbl a where dis =
(select min(dis) from tbl b where b.num = a.num)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have IF logic you can use PL/pgSQL.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html

But try to solve your issue with SQL first if possible, it will be faster and use PL/pgSQL when SQL can't solve your problem.